# Error 410 ("resource no longer available") while getting html code of an url in Python

Tags: python, url, html-parsing

I am trying to  get the html of the following link:

http://www8.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/cases/cth/FCA/2006/3.html

To do so, I proceeded as follows:

```
import requests
try: 
     from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://www8.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/cases/cth/FCA/2006/3.html'
html=requests.get(url)
```

And the html code I get (`print(html.text)`) is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head> 
<title>410 Gone</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Gone</h1>
<p>The requested resource
<br />/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/cases/cth/FCA/2006/3.html<br />
is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address.
Please remove all references to this resource.</p>
</body></html>
```

I don't really get why when the link actually exists and its content too. Indeed, if I go to the link and check there the html is way different of that one I am getting. How could I get the actual text content?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server seems fussy about which user agent is accessing the resource. You can set your own user agent using the `headers` parameter of `requests.get()`:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/cases/cth/FCA/2006/3.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'whatever'}

>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> r
<Response [410]>

>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

The server is rejecting requests that contain substrings such as "curl", "python", "wget" etc. in the `User-Agent` header.

Comment: Thanks, it completely fix it!